# Where should you put application properties in a rebar erlang application?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, rebar

A newbie question: I wrote my first rebar based erlang application. I want to configure some basic properites like server host etc. Where is the best place to put them and how should I load them into the app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next steps are to make a release and create a node in it. A node runs your application in a standalone Erlang VM. A good starting point for creating a release using rebar:

[Erlang Application Management with Rebar](http://alancastro.org/2010/05/01/erlang-application-management-with-rebar.html)

Once you have created a release. The configuration properties for all applications in your node can then be added to

```
{your-app}/{release}/files/sys.config
```

You can read individual properties as follows:

```
Val = application:get_env(APP, KEY)
```

Alternatively, all properties for your application can be read as

```
Config = application:get_all_env(APP)
```

In `sys.config`, properties can be added as a `proplist`.

Example:

```
    {myapp,
      [
       {port, 1234},
       {pool_size, 5}
      ]
    }
```