# specify env settings in command line

Tags: erlang

I have a node that runs several applications. These applications each have specific `env` settings. When I generate a release I start my node by just running `./rel/mynode/bin/mynode start`. Is there an option that I could add to this command to override apps' `env` settings?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242643/where-should-you-put-application-properties-in-a-rebar-erlang-application/9244478#9244478) help?

Comment: thanks. i guess it is preferable than doing this in command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: No, there is no parameter that you can pass into that command to load a different application env file.

However, if you are trying to load a different config file, for example a development file vs. a production file, you should check out how to do [dynamic configuration](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/wiki/Dynamic-configuration) with rebar.

I use it for running my application between different configured environments (production, and local testing).

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get what you mean by `env` settings. If you mean the applications *configuration parameters* that are set in the `{Par,Val}` tuples of the key `env` in the .app files then these can also be overridden in a *system configuration file* or directly in the command line. See the [Configuring an Application](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html#id74284) section.